# How to grab a reference to a MovieClip, and add a child to it

Tags: actionscript-3, movieclip

I'm trying to add a child to a `MovieClip`, but I don't know how to get it into the class of the object I want to add. I have an object called `ground` and a `base` with the class `Base`, when I try to get the `ground` `MovieClip` from the stage, I get an error because it says that it is a `null` object, but it isn't true because in debug, I can see that the var that contains that `MovieClip` has the correct values.

This is the code I wrote:

```
var ground:DisplayObjectContainer = DisplayObjectContainer(parent); 
if(ground.name == "root1")
{
    var ground_movie:MovieClip = ground.getChildByName("ground") as MovieClip;
    ground_movie.addChild(this);
}
```

Comment: Where (what class) is that code written?

Comment: What line triggers the `null object reference` error?

Comment: that is the constructor of the class Base and i don't know what generates the null object reference... It doesn't day that that's the problem

Comment: If the code above is in the `Base` class, then `var ground:DisplayObjectContainer = DisplayObjectContainer(parent);` would reference the `parent` of this instance of `Base`. Next, you're attempting to reference a child by the name of "ground" on the parent of Base. Are you sure that there is a child that exists with the name of "ground" at that display level? When you say that "I can see that the var that contains that `MovieClip` has the correct values, are you referring to `ground_movie`? Are you getting an actual error? If so, where is the error and what is the error code/message?

Comment: `TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.`
 `at Senzanome_1_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()[Senzanome_1_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:20]`
 `at runtime::ContentPlayer/loadInitialContent()`
 `at runtime::ContentPlayer/playRawContent()`
 `at runtime::ContentPlayer/playContent()`
 `at runtime::AppRunner/run()`
 `at ADLAppEntry/run()`
 `at global/runtime::ADLEntry()`
That is the error that I got